# How can $\int_{-3}^3\lfloor{x^2}\rfloor dx = 2 \cdot \int_0^3\lfloor{x^2}\rfloor dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, ceiling-and-floor-functions

[This](http://www.stumblingrobot.com/2015/07/18/compute-integrals-of-some-more-step-functions/#comment-887) website simplifies the integral $$\int_{-3}^3\lfloor{x^2}\rfloor dx$$
into
$$2 \cdot \int_0^3\lfloor x^2 \rfloor dx.$$
How is that done? I'm unsure which property of the integral it is.

The closest I have found is the Homogeneous Property, which states $$\int_a^b c \cdot s(x) dx = c \cdot \int_a^b s(x) dx.$$

Also, note that we are dealing with step functions, and by $\lfloor x^2 \rfloor$, I mean the greatest integer $\le x^2$.

Any insight you could provide as to of how that simplification is made would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: **HINT**: Even function!

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you. You are right. I see now that the simplification can be made because the function is even. Could you tell me why? How the function being even allows us to do that?

Comment: Draw a picture and think about reflection across the $y$-axis. Officially, substitute $u=-x$ in the integral from $-3$ to $0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I think I have firgured it out, and I will answer my own question in a moment. Let me just ask you one final question. Do we take the area under a graph to be positive, even when we are on the negative $x$ axis? If I have an even step function, do we take the area under that step function for negative $x$ values to be positive?

Comment: Area only counts negative if the graph of the function is below the $x$-axis.

Comment: $$\because x^2=(-x)^2$$

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you for your help. How does my answer look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice first that if we define some step function $s(x) = \lfloor x^2 \rfloor$, then $s(x)$ is even, since for all $x$ in the domain of $s$, $s(x) = s(-x)$.

We shall use the property Additivity with Respect to the Interval of Integration to help deduce our solution, which states

$$\int_a^c f(x) dx + \int_c^b f(x) dx = \int_a^b f(x)dx$$

where $a < c < b$.

In this case, taking $a$, $c$, and $b$ to be $-3$, $0$, and $3$ respectively, we may say

$$\int_{-3}^3 \lfloor x^2 \rfloor dx = \int_{-3}^0 \lfloor x^2 \rfloor dx + \int_0^3 \lfloor x^2 \rfloor dx.$$

Observe, then, that since $s(x)$ is even, it's graph is symmetric on both sides of the $y$-axis. Due to this congruency,

$$\int_{-3}^0 \lfloor x^2 \rfloor dx = \int_0^3 \lfloor x^2 \rfloor dx.$$

That means, then, that we are adding the same value twice to compute the full integral. By simple algebra, we may rewrite

$$\int_{-3}^3 \lfloor x^2 \rfloor dx $$

as

$$2 \cdot \int_0^3 \lfloor x^2 \rfloor$$

More generally, when ever we are integrating an even function $f(x)$ along the closed interval $[-a, a]$, we may say

$$\int_{-a}^a f(x) dx = 2 \cdot \int_0^af(x)dx.$$

Comment: Officially, when you learn substitution in integrals, you should show rigorously that $\int_{-a}^0 f(x)\,dx = \int_0^a f(x)\,dx$ when $f(-x)=f(x)$ for all $x$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you. I'm fairly new to rigorous proofs. How would you do it the way you mention? What amendments should I make to my answer?

Comment: @TedShifrin Actually, a proof of the Additive Property is one of the next excersizes in Apostol's Calculus, which is the book I am reading. I'll update my answer with that proof when I get there. Is that what I should do?

Comment: Does Apostol have an exercise to prove that $c\int_a^b f(cx)\,dx = \int_{ca}^{cb} f(x)\,dx$ for any constant $c$? That's what I'm referring to. ... BTW, when you get to multivariable and linear algebra, you might find my YouTube lectures helpful/interesting. (Apostol is a great text.)

Comment: @TedShifrin There is only $\int_{ca}^{cb}f(\frac{x}{c})dx = c \cdot \int_a^b f(x)dx$.
Where can I find your YouTube lectures? I'd be very interested in them.

Comment: These are equivalent results. Figure out why. ;) My lectures are linked in my profile.

Comment: @TedShifrin Do you think your lectures would be helpful for the topics I mention in my profile? Ideally, I would want to learn a mix of theory and practicality to apply toward electronics, physics, computer science, etc.

Comment: Since you picked Apostol as a calculus text, you're obviously interested in understanding and wrestling with some proofs and concepts, not just rote computations. My course is actually at a slightly higher level than Apostol's multivariable, although comparable for a good part of it. When you get through the single-variable calculus to the linear algebra in Volume I, you can start to look at mine. I actually did do a reasonable amount of applications (particularly to physics) at various points ...